# Боковое меню на телефоне

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch-event

Нашел один фреймворк, из всего множества функций заинтересовала [данная](http://materializecss.com/mobile.html):

[image: Пример]
<sub>(источник: [materializecss.com](http://materializecss.com/images/menu.gif))</sub>

Интересно как себе сделать подобное, но например менять ширину элемента по подобной схеме, помогите узнать принцип по которому работает вышеуказанный элемент.

Думаю что будут использоваться :

```
touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Hammer.js для обработки тач событий
А так в исходниках у материлиазцсс есть все необходимое.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Приведите пример, и (или) опишите подробнее функциональность

Comment: materialize.css не решает вопрос. А отправка меня к еще одной библиотеке js не сильно поможет, так как нужно разбираться что да как.  Потому и вопрос был задан здесь  для развернутого ответа.

Comment: Использовал я materialize на одном из проектов, редкостная дрянь, много багов. После того как профиксят баги, попробуйте обновиться, обратной совместимости нет.